# LinkedIn Developer app was not deleted after my linkedIn account was deactivated

Tags: linkedin-api

The issue I am facing right now is very severe. I have already spent more than 1 week, still, linkedIn wasn't able to resolve it and finally they redirect me to SO to ask LinkedIn API related question.

**Actual Issue**: I have created LinkedIn developer app on my linked developer account which helps me to login in my iOS application. Everything was working fine, but due to some reason my account was compromised and I requested LinkedIn support to deactivate my account. Within some days, they deactivated my account. After my account is deactivated I tried to create the same app with same bundle identifier with a different account but it shows me error **"Your application identifier must be unique."**

Since my account is deactivated, I cannot understand why it is not allowing me to create a developer app with same bundle identifier as before.

Does this mean that deactivation of personal account doesn't delete your developer apps and its details?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A deactivated account does not remove a created appId or appBoundle from a pool of created apps.

The Google Firebase has the same strategy about created app identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Then how to resolve this issue? LinkedIn support team is not helping me in this term.

Comment: There is no solution for that except you will get back your previous account.